# Why doesn't my controller return JSON response?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

here is the code

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all.includes(:todos) 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json  @projects => @projects.to_json(:include => :todos) }
  end
end
```

I try to obtain JSON from my Android app using Ion like so

```
String serverAdress = "https://the-url.com/"
Ion.with(context)
            .load(serverAdress)
            .asJsonObject()
```

but get parsing error, because nothing returned from there. I am able to obtain JSON if there is separate controller method which returns JSON response exclusively, so this code worked

```
def indexJson
  @projects = Project.all.includes(:todos) 
  render json  @projects => @projects.to_json(:include => :todos)
end
```

but again, I wasn't able to post anything there (I mean other separate JSON controller methods). What have I missed in rails settings or when obtaining data? Thank you.

Comment: What JSON do you get back in the second example? It looks a little funky to me in that it's using a collection of projects as the key AND their JSONified selves as the values. I'm not sure this is the central issue as I don't know anything about the Android code, but maybe worth looking at.... (Also, quick note: `Project.includes(:todos)` will suffice here - no need for the `all` :) )

Comment: @SRack It's send by default, I do not bother with changing it. It seems that rails expects some defined kind of request. I don't know what must be in header for rails to acknowledge it as JSON request. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance I encountered some controller comment on some website

```
# GET /projects
# GET /projects.json
```

and tried to append '.json' to my address request, and it worked! Why isn't it told anywhere?, I thought that 'json' is somewhere in the request parameters, not in address itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to json request from Ion in order to get JSON response.

In second case you haven't defined HTML return format so rails by default is sending you json response, that's why second case is working

Comment: As far as I understand, Ion sends JSON requests by default. I tried to set explicitly .setMultipartContentType("application/json"), but got error  'connection closed before response completed.' I don't know what kind of request rails expects.